# Automatic Encryption and Decryption of Column in MySql

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

I wanted to encrypt and decrypt a column in MySql table based on the User logging in. Lets say when a normal user **"John"** logs in he should see that column encrypted, but when a super user **"root"** logs in he should see the column as plan text (decrypted). Is it possible in MYSQL or any other DataBase to acheive such user level security. I don't want to use any of the MYSQL Encrypt() and Decrypt() functions.

Thanks

Ganesh.R

Comment: Are those "users" database users (accessing MySQL directly)? Or is this a three-tier application (with application-level users that share a database account)?

Comment: @Thilo They are database users accessing the database directly.

Comment: @diEcho: to do what? Store the unencrypted version in addition to the encrypted one? That makes no sense.

Comment: any luck in getting this done ??